# How to avoid pigeons eating my dog's food and pooping my car / front yard?

Tags: home, car, pest-control, pets

I keep my dog's food and water on my backyard, pigeons eat all his food and drink his water every time they get the chance. My dog stays on the front yard most of the time and whenever he sees pigeons, he tries to shoo them away.

So I tried putting my dog's food and water on the front yard so he can scare them more frequently. But they still somehow manage to eat his food. To make things worse, pigeons stay on the roof guarding and waiting for their chance to steal while pooping my car. Now everything is a mess.

A friend said to me he tried putting a fake and nice cat near where pigeons stay saying it works, but it only worked for a few weeks because eventually, they find out it is a fake.

Is there any other way to definitely keep them away?

Comment: I was going to suggest a plastic owl, but apparently that only works initially. After a while, the pigeons figure out that the owl won't attack them, and they'll come back.

Comment: To keep them from eating the dog's food, feed the dog inside.  Use a cover on the car.  Depending on your location, you can use a shotgun, pellet gun, slingshot &c, and do a search on "pigeon recipies".

Comment: I would build a speaker, a small one not massive, that plays a predator bird's sounds every other hour I don't know seems like a fun project and it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the fake cat around every so often, they're likely to be uncomfortable at the possibility it could be alive. I would otherwise suggest placing shiny wind chimes near the dog's bowl, the light reflecting and the sound may startle them away.

Pigeons and many wild birds are deterred from things moving nearby that are bigger than them (flight over fight every time). So there are a few things you could try for trial and error such as the wind chimes and possibly a water sprinkler.

Good Luck with the pest control!

Comment: Plastic/wooden snakes work well too. But you must move them every couple days or so

Comment: @Aranzi Thanks, will try the wind chimes, although I think it won't scare the pigeons enough, especially when there is no wind.

Comment: @user3546771 Oh ok, Just a quick thought, I've not tried this, but rather than scaring the pigeons away, how about leading them to a more tempting bird bath and bird feeder. It may become a social spot for them but chances are they will stay away from the dog's food/water

Answer (score 3):

You can feed your dog in a cage made of metal net and a roof. It may have a door for the dog. This door can be like the ones which are like small door on home doors. I think they call them dog door flaps.

This way the dog can enter to eat but the pigeons can't enter, they are not strong enough to push the door.

Comment: Unfortunately my dog does not like to eat in "closed areas". The fact of entering small cage-box makes him uncomfortable.

Comment: The dog will learn to eat in a cage when he gets hungry enough. He just needs to discover that the only options are "eat in a cage" and "eat nothing".